# Add Variable to lazyMap Reference

Tags: groovy

I am looking to pass in a `String` to a function that will allow me to dynamically change the key that I am looking for in a `LazyMap`

```
public analyzeLazyMap(String valueToCheck, String keyToAnalyze, ArrayList<LazyMap> arrayOfLazyMaps){
    for (LazyMap myLazyMap in arrayOfLazyMaps) {
        if (valueToCheck == myLazyMap.$keyToAnalyze) {
             return 'bar'
        }
    }
}
```

So in this call I would expect myKey to go into the "Do Something" section". Assume `foobar` will be in `myArrayListofLazyMaps`

```
String foo = analyzeLazyMap('foobar', 'myKey', myArrayListofLazyMaps,)
println(foo)
//Console Output == bar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, figured this out. My data going was not correct

```
 public analyzeLazyMap(String valueToCheck, String keyToAnalyze, ArrayList<LazyMap> arrayOfLazyMaps){
     for (LazyMap myLazyMap in arrayOfLazyMaps) {
         if (valueToCheck == myLazyMap."$keyToAnalyze") {
              return 'bar'
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of syntax sugar

```
arrayOfLazyMaps.each {lazyMap ->
    if (lazyMap."$keyToAnalyze" == valueToCheck)
        return 'bar'
}
```